# How to launch a function from a module so that it takes effect in the main program?

Tags: python

An example of what I want to get:

Main program:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter  as tk 
import module


main_window = Tk()


def createCanvas():

    canvas = Canvas(main_window, bg="grey")
    canvas.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)


def resetCanvas():

    canvas.destroy()
    createCanvas()


button1 = Button(main_window, text="launch module", command=module.moduleFunction)
button1.grid(row=0, column=0)

button2 = Button(main_window, text="reset canvas", command=resetCanvas)
button2.grid(row=0, column=1)

createCanvas()

main_window.mainloop()
```

Module:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter  as tk
from tkinter import Toplevel


def moduleFunction():

    child_window = Toplevel()

    def resetCanvasFromModule():

        # THE QUESTION!
        resetCanvas() 


    button3 = Button(child_window, text="reset canvas from module", command=resetCanvasFromModule)
    button3.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Obviously this doesn't work, since resetCanvas() isn't defined inside the module, but if I define it, it will try to destroy canvas, which isn't defined in the module, so it won't work either.

So, what would I have to do to get the effect I want?

P.S.: I have tried with 'global', without success.

Comment: return the canvas from the module method, keep it around in a variable,  same for resetCanvas .... if you want to create a canvas on the outside, you can pass it into methods as well: `def moduleFunction(myCanvas): ... ` - Am I not quite getting what you are asking?

Comment: Well, in my actual program, 'canvas' displays information from a database, and 'module' allows to modify the database records.
What I want is that when I modify the records via 'module', 'canvas' is reset to show the new information in the main window, without having to launch manually the function that resets it (resetCanvas).

Comment: Then pass in your "whatever canvas" into any methods that need to call its update - of passs in a delegate lamda function they can call:  `def changeData(new_data, resetIt):  # do data changes; resetIt()`  and use with `changeData(some_data, resetCanvas)` from your code. You cann pass in the "function name" as is and call it under the new given param name in your dependend code - plente of better ways to do it

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just pass the element?
like this
from tkinter import *

```
canvas = None

def createCanvas():
    global canvas
    canvas = Canvas(main_window, bg="grey")
    canvas.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

def ResetCanvasFromModule():
    global canvas
    canvas.forget()
    createCanvas()

button1 = Button(main_window, text="create canvas", command=createCanvas)
button1.grid(row=0, column=0)

button2 = Button(main_window, text="reset canvas", command=ResetCanvas)
button2.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys.

Passing resetCanvas() as a parameter to moduleFunction(), and a lambda as button1 command, works fine.

This is my working example code(maybe in the future it can be useful to a newbie like me):

Main code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter  as tk 
import module


main_window = Tk()


def createCanvas():
    global canvas
    canvas = Canvas(main_window, bg="grey")
    canvas.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
    return
    canvas

def resetCanvas():

    canvas.destroy()
    createCanvas()


button1 = Button(main_window, text="launch module", command=lambda:[module.moduleFunction(resetCanvas)])
button1.grid(row=0, column=0)

button2 = Button(main_window, text="reset canvas", command=resetCanvas)
button2.grid(row=0, column=1)

createCanvas()


main_window.mainloop()
```

Module:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter  as tk
from tkinter import Toplevel



def moduleFunction(resetCanvas):

    child_window = Toplevel()

    def resetCanvasFromModule():
        
        resetCanvas() 


    button3 = Button(child_window, text="reset canvas from module", command=resetCanvasFromModule)
    button3.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Thanks a lot.